# Load data from a file to SQL Managed Instance

Tags: sql, azure-sql-managed-instance

From what I understand SQL Managed Instance cannot access local or external file share.

We are trying to load data from a file to SQL Managed Instance, wanted recommendations on the best approach for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use BULK INSERT from Azure blob storage https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-SQL-Database/Loading-files-from-Azure-Blob-Storage-into-Azure-SQL-Database/ba-p/386133

1. Upload your files to azure storage
2. Create external data source to that location  (put SAS token if it is not public):

````
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage 
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE, LOCATION = 'https://myazureblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net'); ```
````

3. Load files from this account.

```
BULK INSERT Product 
FROM 'data/product.dat' 
WITH ( DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorageAccount');
```

Comment: This is for Azure SQL, Not managed instance. I don't think this works in MI at all (still working it out)